# Python Regex Spam Filter

Tags: python, regex

I am working on a anti-spam chat bot and have been using the following Regex to catch spammers.

```
spam = re.compile(ur'(?:\b(\w+)\b) (?:\1(?: |$))+')
```

But, the issue with this is that it triggers when the same word repeated twice. How do i make this so it triggers if the word is repeated 4 times in total not just 2 times?

Comment: Read about "regex quantifiers". Check the [regex reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075). Also your example doesn't "just match 2 times".

Comment: HamZa nailed it, here's a resource for python: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1278986

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for 4 times in a row.
More generally, you can replace space `[ ]` with whitespace `\s+` and allow for some separation.

```
 # \b(\w+)(?:[ ]\1(?=[ ]|$)){3}

 \b 
 ( \w+ )                # (1), One
 (?:                    # Plus
      [ ] 
      \1                # Three
      (?= [ ] | $ )
 ){3}
                        # Four Total
```